# HTML <input> element not POSTing value?

Tags: php, html, cross-browser

Okay, this is a weird one.

Best I can tell, my code is correct. And it works in Safari on a Mac, Safari on an iPhone and Google Chrome on an Android tablet. What it *doesn't* work on, however, is Firefox or Internet Explorer; and I can't for the life of me figure out why!

The problem is this: That when I click an `<input>` tag, and the form is submitted, the value of this tag is not being POSTed. Even stranger, the X and Y values *are* being posted - this being an image input tag - but no value.

Here is the relevant piece of HTML:

```
<input type='image' name="edit" value="59" class="news-control news-control-hidden" src="assets/edit.png"/></input>
```

Here are the values that are POSTed when I click the tag, as output by a `print_r($_POST)` call:

```
Array ( [edit_x] => 29 [edit_y] => 9 )
```

I have the following code on my PHP web page:

```
<form name="newsform" method="post" action="Admin.php">
    <table class="editable-list">
<?php
        $entries = get_news_posts();
        if (empty($entries)) {
?>
            <tr><td><p style='margin: 6px 10px 16px 0px'>No news posts exist.<br><br>Click the button below to create one.</p></td></tr>
<?php
        } else
            foreach ($entries as $row) {
                make_editable_news_item($row['date'], $row['content'], $row['ID'], isset($_POST['edit']) ? $_POST['edit'] : null);
            }
        if (!isset($_POST['edit'])) {
?>
            <tr><td class='news-add-post' colspan='7'>
                <input type="submit" name="create_new" value="Create new post"/><br>
            </td></tr>
<?php                       }       ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

I also have this function:

```
    function make_editable_news_item($datestamp, $content, $id, $editing_id) {
?>
    <tr class="news-item">
        <td class="news-controls">
<?php   if ($id == $editing_id) {       ?>
                <input type='image' class="news-control" src="assets/undo.png"/></input>
<?php       } else if (!isset($editing_id)) {                   ?>
                <input type='image' name="edit" value="<?= $id ?>" class="news-control news-control-hidden" src="assets/edit.png"/></input>
<?php       }       ?>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="news-datestamp">
            <?= format_datestamp($datestamp) ?>
<?php   if ($id == $editing_id) {       ?>
                <div style="background-color: #eee; height: 1px; margin: 6px;"></div>
                <div class="news-control-datestamp">
                    <input name='update_date' class="news-control-datestamp" type="checkbox">
                        Update
                    </input>
                </div>
<?php       }       ?>
        </td>
        <td class="news-separator"/>
        <td class="news-divider"/>
        <td class="news-separator"/>
        <td class="news-content">
<?php   if ($id == $editing_id) {       ?>
                <textarea name="content" class="news-content"><?= $content ?></textarea>
<?php   } else {    ?>
                <div class="news-content"><?= $content ?></div>
<?php       }       ?>
        </td>
        <td class="news-separator"/>
        <td class="news-separator"/>
        <td class="news-separator"/>
        <td class="news-controls">
<?php   if ($id == $editing_id) {       ?>
                <input type='image' name='save' value='<?= $id ?>' class="news-control" src="assets/save.png"/></input>
<?php       } else if (!isset($editing_id)) {                   ?>
                <input type='image' name="delete" value="<?= $id ?>" class="news-control news-control-hidden" src="assets/delete.png"/></input>
<?php       }       ?>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="news-separator"></tr>
<?php } ?>
```

This code gives rise to the following HTML:

```
<form name="newsform" method="post" action="Admin.php">
    <table class="editable-list">
    <tr class="news-item">
        <td class="news-controls">
            <input type='image' name="edit" value="59" class="news-control news-control-hidden" src="assets/edit.png"/></input>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="news-datestamp">     5th Dec 2015<br>11:12pm         </td>
        <td class="news-separator"/>
        <td class="news-divider"/>
        <td class="news-separator"/>
        <td class="news-content">
            <div class="news-content">...</div>
        </td>
        <td class="news-separator"/>
        <td class="news-separator"/>
        <td class="news-separator"/>
        <td class="news-controls">
            <input type='image' name="delete" value="59" class="news-control news-control-hidden" src="assets/delete.png"/></input>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="news-separator"></tr>
        <tr><td class='news-add-post' colspan='7'>
            <input type="submit" name="create_new" value="Create new post"/><br>
        </td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

So the question is, why don't Firefox and IE respect the input tag's `value` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image inputs are supposed to be used for server side image maps.

They don't post their values, they post (as `name.x` and `name.y` (PHP converts `.` to `_` because you can't have `.` in a variable name so it would have failed with the old, default *register globals*)) the coordinates of the pixel you clicked on.

If you want to pass a value, use a regular submit button instead.

```
<button name="edit" value="59">
    <img src="assets/edit.png" alt="Edit: 59">
</button>
```

Comment: They certainly do post their values, in Safari and Chrome ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, using nested <button>/<img> tags causes a button-style appearance in Firefox; rather than the nice clean image appearance I want. There is a gradianted grey background and a grey border; the image is not centered correctly within the button, and the button is wider than it is tall. My css for this element is:
  text-decoration: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 2px;
 width: 36;
 height: 36;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: 1px solid white;
 background-color: white;

Comment: I don't get that in my copy of Firefox. https://www.evernote.com/l/AAM8eSAtxJdP-L0HZZOQzOIW4-DZ6fgB_Mw

Comment: I do. Check this out. Firefox on the left, Safari on the right:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36875370/Screen%20Shot%202015-12-06%20at%2000.26.38.png

Comment: Well, that's odd. I refreshed the page again and it looked right. Some kind of cache issue, possibly? Anyway, thanks for the help!